# How to make a Validation for only one custom field on Opencart - resolved

Tags: php, json, opencart

Hi i'd like to make a validation for a specific custom field on Opencart 2.3.0.2. On my code i had to disable the default validation, so i need to make a validation for only one custom field on form. The custom field called "NUMBER", is the number of customer's address. The validation purpose is check if the field is empty or not. So i'm making this

```
$this->load->model('account/custom_field');

            $custom_fields = $this->model_account_custom_field->getCustomFields($this->config->get('config_customer_group_id'));

            foreach ($custom_fields as $custom_field) {
                if (($custom_field['location'] == 'address') && $custom_field['required'] && empty($this->request->post['custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id'] == 7])) {$json['error']['custom_field' . $custom_field['custom_field_id'] == 7] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_custom_field'), $custom_field['name']);}}
```

But when i submit the form its not showing any error or the div with text danger. Can anyone helps with this code. I'm grateful

The opencart has a default code in array who validate all the field. What i did was delete this validate configuration and make for only one field. So, the default validation for custom field located on checkout/checkout - shiping_address form is,

```
foreach ($custom_fields as $custom_field) {
                if (($custom_field['location'] == 'address') && $custom_field['required'] && empty($this->request->post['custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id']])) {
                    $json['error']['custom_field' . $custom_field['custom_field_id']] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_custom_field'), $custom_field['name']);
                } elseif (($custom_field['location'] == 'address') && ($custom_field['type'] == 'text') && !empty($custom_field['validation']) && !filter_var($this->request->post['custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id']], FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array('options' => array('regexp' => '/' . html_entity_decode($custom_field['validation'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '/')))) {
                    $json['error']['custom_field' . $custom_field['custom_field_id']] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_custom_field'), $custom_field['name']);
                }
            }
```

i commented this code and make this modification

```
foreach ($custom_fields as $custom_field) {
                if (($custom_field['location'] == 'address') && $custom_field['required'] && empty($this->request->post['custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id']])) {

                    //number field
                    if($custom_field['custom_field_id'] == 7) {
                    $json['error']['custom_field' . $custom_field['custom_field_id']] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_custom_field'), $custom_field['name']);
                    }

                } elseif (($custom_field['location'] == 'address') && ($custom_field['type'] == 'text') && !empty($custom_field['validation']) && !filter_var($this->request->post['custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id']], FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array('options' => array('regexp' => '/' . html_entity_decode($custom_field['validation'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '/')))) {
                    $json['error']['custom_field' . $custom_field['custom_field_id']] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_custom_field'), $custom_field['name']);
                }
            }
```

i just make a condition checking if is custom_field 7, if empty, shows the error

Comment: Why are you checking `empty($variable == 7)`? That's plain weird.  I can't figure your strategy.

Comment: I'm trying to check if custom field 7 is empty. If empty shows the text-danger if not, just submit the form

Comment: I assure you, that is not what your code is doing.  Your code is checking if `$this->request->post['custom_field'][boolean]` is empty.  I cannot see your `post` array, so your question is Unclear and I cannot help you.

Comment: Maybe this will clarify your issue: https://3v4l.org/PrAmj

Comment: I edited my question putting the array about foreach ($custom_fields as $custom_field) {

Comment: About your link, i dont understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate the condition logic.  Right now you have compacted your syntax and damaged the logic.

```
empty($this->request->post['custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id'] == 7])
// this is performing an evaluation -------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// returning a true or false value
// if false, the key is converted to 0 because false isn't a valid key
// if true, the key is converted to 1
```

The trouble is you don't have those numeric keys in `$this->request->post['custom_field']`, so they will make `empty()` return `true`.
Use this instead:

```
if ($custom_field['location'] == 'address'
    && $custom_field['required']
    && // iterate your post array and check $post['custom_field_id'] == 7
    && // iterate your post array and check empty($post['custom_field_value'])) {
```

Comment: You're right, its not making  a selection, if is empty or not. I tried your code, and i configured to show like this: if is empty shows: is empty, if not is fulled. The log error shows me both messages

Comment: Have I resolved your question then? Or do you need help looping through the post array?

Comment: I just noticed that you are looping through `$custom_fields`, not the post array.  You are going to need to loop through that and keep looking for the subarray containing the lucky number 7.

Comment: I changed my question with the solution. I appreciate it your help, i learned too much

Comment: Your code is too long for me to read properly on my phone, but `array('regexp' => '/' . html_entity_decode($custom_field['validation'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '/')` doesn't look good.  I recommend studying `preg_quote()`. I think that is what you are intending to do.

Comment: If my answer resolved your issue, you can mark my answer with the green tick.